# java one dimensional string to multidimensional

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, split

I am given a string that can represent hex values and am told to convert it to such and store it in a string:

```
String str = new String("FF E7 C3 E7 FF");
String[] arrayStr = str.split(" ");
```

Then I need to convert each hex value to its binary equivalent:

```
String[] arrayBin = new String[arrayStr.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayStr.length; i++) {
        arrayBin[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(arrayStr[i],16));
}
```

This is where I get lost. Is this binary string technically one dimensional or two dimensional? Basically, I need to convert it to a two dimensional array so that I can iterate through it in both x and y directions, to perform something like this:

```
for (int k = 0; k < arrayBin.length; k++) {
    for (int l = 0; l < arrayBin[k].length; l++) {
        if (arrayBin[k][l] == "1") {
            arrayBin[k][l] = "x";
        } else {
            arrayBin[k][l] = " ";               
        }
    }
}
```

At this point I get nothing but compiler errors, and despite all the articles online about multidimensional arrays, no search has given me something that works. I have tried things like:

```
String[][] arrayBin2 = new String[arrayBin.length][]
for (int m = 0; m < arrayBin.length; m++) {
    arrayBin2[m][] = arrayBin[m];
}
```

But that did not work. Any help or suggestions as to what I am doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

---

Second attempt in response to @Eran 's suggestions:

```
public class Challenge3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = new String("FF E7 C3 E7 FF");
        String[] arrayStr = str.split(" ");
        String[] arrayBin = new String[arrayStr.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayStr.length; i++) {
            arrayBin[i] = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(arrayStr[i],16));
        }

        for (int k = 0; k < arrayBin.length; k++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arrayBin[k].length());     
            for (int l = 0; l < arrayBin[k].length(); l++) {
                if (arrayBin[k].charAt(l) == 1) {
                    sb.append("x");
                } else {
                    sb.append(" ");            
                }
            }
            arrayBin[k] = sb.toString();
            System.out.println(arrayBin);
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, the code is supposed to print out the following when done correctly:

```
xxxxxxxx
xxx  xxx
xx    xx
xxx  xxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Comment: Using == to compare two Strings in Java is bad because both Strings need to point to the same object for that to be true. Use arrayBin[k][l].equals("1")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `arrayBin` is 1-dimentional.

If you want to iterate over the bits of each binary `String`, use the methods `length()` and `charAt()` of the `String` class :

```
for (int k = 0; k < arrayBin.length; k++) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(arrayBin[k].length());
    for (int l = 0; l < arrayBin[k].length(); l++) {
        if (arrayBin[k].charAt(l) == '1') {
            sb.append ('x');
        } else {
            sb.append (' ');            
        }
    }
    arrayBin[k] = sb.toString();
    System.out.println(arrayBin[k]);
}
```

Output :

```
xxxxxxxx
xxx  xxx
xx    xx
xxx  xxx
xxxxxxxx
```

Note that you can't change the String instances in your `arrayBin` array, since `String` is immutable. What you can do is construct a new String and replace each String in the `arrayBin` array with the new String.

Comment: I tried to add your code in, and it compiles, but when I print it out all I get are blank lines, no actual content. I had to change the .equals("1") part to "== 1" because otherwise it wouldn't compile (not sure why not). I have edited and added the full code with your suggestions to my original post, under the dashed. thanks for the help.

Comment: @resu Note that in your updated code there are two problems - `== 1` should be `== '1'` and you should print each String of the array separately (see modified code in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the help @Eran , after seeing the answer I feel that I should totally re-name this post, since what I thought the problem was, and what the problem really was, were not the same.